# Labels with matplot

Tags: r, plot, label

I created a plot with multiple lines using matplot:

```
matplot(a, cbind(b,c,d,e), pch=1)
```

where the arguments of cbind are functions of a, for example

```
b <- 2a+3
c <- 3a+2
```

and so forth.

How do add the corresponding labels to the resulting lines?

Comment: What do you exactly mean by "labels to the resulting lines"? Would you like to add a legend or named y-axis? (If so, ?matplot has a good example) Otherwise, it's helpful to describe your desired output.

Comment: I find the ?matplot example quite confusing. Could you indicate the legend code with the functions I wrote above?

Answer (score 7):

Sure, how about this?

```
a <- rnorm(100)
b <- 2*a + 3
c <- 3*a + 2
matplot(a, cbind(b,c), pch=1, col=c(2,4))
legend("bottomright", inset=.05, legend=c("b", "c"), pch=1, col=c(2,4), horiz=TRUE)
```

Brief explanations:

- bottomright is the location of the legend. you can use coordinates instead.
- insett is a distance from margin
- lengend, pch, and col arguments specify the content and style of the legend
- horz makes the legend displayed horizontally (suitable for short variable names)